# Detect if Entity Framework model is too old for database using MigrationHistory

Tags: entity-framework-6, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

We switched from manually coding database migrations to code-first Entity Framework migrations. In our old setup we were able to check whether the database is too new. This is important because it will probably be incompatible. Unfortunately I can't find a nice way to check how up-to-date the current database is or whether it is too old.

The use case is that a client has 2 versions of our software on his computer. The client first starts the newest version that contains more recent migrations than the older version. Afterwards the client starts the older version of the software. Currently the software will crash and burn because the model is incompatible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
DbMigrator.GetPendingMigrations
```

to check if the database is in sync

You can use

```
DbMigrator.GetDatabaseMigrations
```

to check what migrations have been applied to the target database.

And then run the pending migrations as required:

```
var configuration = new Configuration();
var migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);
migrator.Update();
```

http://romiller.com/2012/02/09/running-scripting-migrations-from-code/

Comment: This will not allow me to check whether the database is a migration ahead of the software though or does it?

Comment: I'm now comparing the number of database migrations and model migrations to see which one is newer. I guess merging migrations in the future will be a sin, because that will fool the simple check.